# Why do I need to explicitly detach a short term variable?

Tags: c++, multithreading, std, stdthread

Let's say I have a small operation which I want to perform in a separate thread. I do not need to know when it completes, nor do I need to wait for its completion, but I do not want the operation blocking my current thread. When I write the following code, I will get a crash:

```
void myFunction() {
    // do other stuff
    std::thread([]()
    {
        // do thread stuff
    });
}
```

This crash is solved by assigning the thread to a variable, and detaching it:

```
void myFunction() {
    // do other stuff
    std::thread t([]()
    {
        // do thread stuff
    });
    t.detach();
}
```

Why is this step necessary? Or is there a better way to create a small single-use thread?

Comment: What about `std::thread([]() { }).detach();`? Is the lack of variable causing the crash or the lack of detach?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a duplicate. This question is asking about why `std::thread` has this design, not how to make a crash go away.

Comment: @Sneftel That was indeed my question.

Comment: I agree.  The OP had already identified the need for `.detach` - it was *why*, and whether there is a better way.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow It's the lack of detach ... so that is an answer.

Comment: You can use `boost::thread` if you want the implicit detach.

Comment: If you just want generic background work, you might get better semantics out of [`std::async`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Because the `std::thread::~thread()` specification says so](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/%7Ethread):

> A thread object does not have an associated thread (and is safe to destroy) after
>
> - it was default-constructed
> - it was moved from
> - join() has been called
> - detach() has been called

It looks like `detach()` is the only one of these that makes sense in your case, unless you want to return the thread object (by moving) to the caller.

> Why is this step necessary?

Consider that the thread object represents a long-running "thread" of execution (a lightweight process or kernel schedulable entity or similar).

Allowing you to destroy the object while the thread is still executing, leaves you no way to subsequently join (and find the result of) that thread. This *may* be a logical error, but it can also make it hard even to correctly exit your program.

> Or is there a better way to create a small single-use thread?

Not obviously, but it's frequently better to use a thread pool for running tasks in the background, instead of starting and stopping lots of short-lived threads.

You might be able to use [`std::async()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) instead, but the `future` it returns *may* block in the destructor in some circumstances, if you try to discard it.

Answer (score 0):

See [the documentation of the destructor of `std:thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/~thread):

> If `*this` has an associated thread `(joinable() == true)`, `std::terminate()` is called.

You should explicitly say that you don't care what's going to happen with the thread, and that you're OK with loosing any control over it. And that is what `detach` is for.

In general, this looks like a design problem so crashing makes sense: it's hard to propose a general and not surprising rule about what should happen in such a case (e.g. your program might as well normally end its execution - what should happen with the thread?).

Answer (score 0):

Consider this: thread A creates thread B and thread A leaves its scope of execution. The handle for thread B is about to be lost. What should happen now? There are several possibilities, with most obvious as follows:

1. Thread B is detached and continues its execution indempedently
2. Thread A waits (joins) thread B before quiting its own scope

Now you can argue which is better: 1 or 2? How should we (the compiler) decide on which one of these is better?

So what the designers did was something different: <s>crash</s> terminate the code so that the developer picks one of these solutions explicitely. In order to avoid implicit (perhaps unwanted) behaviuor. It's a signal for you: "hey, pay attention now, this piece of code is important and I (the compiler) don't want to decide for you".

Comment: Either way is acceptable. But what I find disturbing is the "I will get a crash" behavior. The destructor should do something sane. For example default is to wait. Unless you detach. The thread can have a flag internally so the destructor knows when it was detached. Well, it must already have that or detach wouldn't prevent the crash. Note: python waits. Not always the best but better than crashing (by which I assume segfault).

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow I know that either is acceptable. But the "I will crash" behaviour was introduced so that coders make an explicit decision. Joining by default introduces overhead. Detaching by default is error prone. It's not that obvious which one to choose as default behaviour. That's how I imagine C++ developers' way of thinking.

Comment: BTW that's not a segfault. It's simple terminate.

Comment: Ah, terminate() is something else. Sorry, I took "crash" to literal.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your use case requires a call to `detach()` because your use case is *pretty weird*, and not what C++ is trying to make easy.

While Java and .Net blithely let you toss away a `Thread` object whose associated thread is still running, in the C++ model the `Thread` is closer to *being* the thread, in the sense that the existence of the `Thread` object coincides with the lifetime, or at least joinability, of the execution it refers to. Note how it's not possible to create a `Thread` without starting it (except in the case of the default constructor, which is really just there in the service of move semantics), or to copy it or to make one from a thread id. C++ wants `Thread` to outlive the thread.

Maintaining that condition has various benefits. Final cleanup of a thread's control data doesn't have to be done automagically by the OS, because once a `Thread` goes away, nothing can ever try to join it. It's easier to ensure that variables with thread storage get destroyed in time, since the main thread is the last to exit (barring some move shenanigans). And a missing `join` -- which is an *extremely* common type of bug -- gets properly flagged at runtime.

Letting some thread wander off into the distance, in contrast, is *allowed*, but it's an unusual thing to do. Unless it's interacting with your other threads through sync objects, there's no way to ensure it's done whatever it was meant to do. A detached thread is on the level of `reinterpret_cast`: You're allowed to tell the compiler that you know something it doesn't, but that has to be explicit, not just the consequence of the function you *didn't* call.

Comment: IMO there is nothing weird about wanting to create a thread, and then forget about it. The Java world has a name for that pattern: a _daemon thread_ sits in the background, for as long as the process continues to run, waiting for and dealing with some recurring event. (Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crash-only_software).

Comment: @jameslarge Java has different thread termination semantics which make that a more practical pattern. Having a thread run like that in C++ would be quite dangerous.

Comment: Thread termination semantics? The Java Runtime Environment does not give existing threads any warning before a Java process terminates. (One can register a handler function that will be called in a _new_ thread to notify the application of a _clean_ JVM shutdown.) But, I don't get how a Java daemon thread is _implicitly_ any less dangerous than a C++ detached thread.

Comment: @jameslarge Because a Java thread can just *go away* when the runtime needs it to. Since Java is GC'ed, there's no need to unwind the stack, something that's generally impossible to do asynchronously in a RAII-ish language. Note the lack of any C++ counterpart to Java's `Thread.stop()`. (It's not something you want in user code in Java either, obviously, but the underlying functionality is core to how daemon threads work in Java.)

Comment: @jameslarge Additionally, the JVM is sandboxed from the runtime. That means that Java threads, at any given moment (or, at least, at any safepoint), can be killed without corrupting, say, the memory allocator. The same can't be said of C++, making it infeasible to robustly shut down the runtime while any other threads are running.

Comment: My mistake. I thought we were talking about the weirdness/advisability of allowing an application to `detach()` a thread, thereby allowing it to continue running right up until the instant when the process is terminated.